# bateman-horn conjecture

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

The Bateman-Horn conjecture gives a fairly accurate representation on the density of primes in a polynomial. I understand that the Bateman-Horn Conjecture is not yet proven, but I was curious on what upper bounds have been proven to estimate the same thing? It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can reference me to any papers or research on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is "sieve methods". Research monographs by Halberstam and Richert, and more recently by Friedlander and Iwaniec, collect a vast amount of results of the type you mention.

A sound-bite answer to your specific question: given any polynomial $F(t)$, there exists an absolute constant $C$ depending only on the degree of $F$ such that the number of prime values of $F(n)$ with $n\le x$ is no more than $C$ times the expected number of prime values given by the Bateman–Horn conjecture.